# jQuery Toggle opacity of an element inside the previous sibling

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, opacity

I have an image and a div below which has a slide toggle effect when an 'About' button is clicked.

[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/3SA4d/1/)

HTML

```
<section class="watch-block">
<div class="illustration-wrapper">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" title="watch text"/>
</div>
<div class="watch-text hide-first">
<div class="inner-padding text-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quibusdam fugit cum dignissimos quas voluptatibus tenetur magni, voluptates dolores veniam sapiente sunt aut perspiciatis laudantium, dolor pariatur sit excepturi nemo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quibusdam fugit cum dignissimos quas voluptatibus tenetur magni, voluptates dolores veniam sapiente sunt aut perspiciatis laudantium, dolor pariatur sit excepturi nemo.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle-wrapper"><span>About</span></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.watch-block {width:400px;}     
.illustration-wrapper {background-color: red;}
.illustration-wrapper img {display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em 0;}
.watch-text {color: #fff; text-align: center;}
.toggle-wrapper {width: 40px;height: 40px;margin: 0 auto;}
.watch-text, .toggle-wrapper {background-color:#FF530D; cursor: pointer;}
.watch-text p:first-child {margin-top: 0;}
.watch-text .inner-padding {padding: 2em;}
```

jQuery

```
$(".hide-first").hide();
$(".toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
$(this).prev(".hide-first").animate({ height: "toggle"}); 
});
```

How can I get the text `.text-content` to fade in when users click to show the div and then fade out the text when the user clicks to hide the div?

As you can see, I know how to target the previous sibling `.hide-first` on click but how can I apply an animation to an element nested inside that previous sibling?

Comment: what dont you just select that by its class name ? like `$(".text-content").fadeToggle();` . or `$(this).prev(".hide-first").childeren(".text-content").fadeToggle();` .

Comment: @JafarRasooli - sorry I tried these but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jquery**

```
    $(".hide-first").hide();
    $(".toggle-wrapper").click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".hide-first").find('.text-content').animate( {opacity:"toggle" });
    $(this).prev(".hide-first").animate({ height: "toggle"});  
     });
```

**css**

```
.text-content{display:none}
```

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LR35/2/)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it makes the background colour of the sliding div also fade in/out... I want the sliding div background colour to be solid when sliding down/up and I only want the text content to fade in.

Comment: I have updated my commment and the fiddle with what you wanted

Comment: That's brilliant thanks! In the CSS I was putting `.text-content{opacity:0;}` and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working...